# htaccess redirecting by ip range

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to block off range of ip addresses by using below commands in .htaccess file.

So 1.2.3.0 - 1.2.3.154 needs to be blocked for example but it's not working. Why is this the case?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} ^1\.2\.3\.0/154
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/australia-ip-restriction?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/templates/?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/files/?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(.*)$
RewriteRule /(.*)$ /australia-ip-restriction [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Do you have to use a rewrite rule, rather than just using mod_access?

Comment: Doesn't matter I just need to redirect list of Ip ranges

Comment: Okay, that's a little different. Redirecting is different from banning.

Comment: Also, don't ban us, we're nice people! :-)

Comment: Sorry. I just need to redirect. I changed the title...:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Redirecting and Blocking IP addresses with REGEX is risky.** You can accidentally block or create a redirect loop for all traffic to your site, so you'll want some sort of countermeasures in place. Check log files to make sure the results you're seeking are actually working and watch for false positives. Visit the pages, make sure they work as intended. Test with a proxy for out-of-country IP access restrictions.

There are registrars around the world where you can look up various IP addresses: [Ripe.net](http://www.ripe.net/), [APNIC.net](http://www.apnic.net/), [Arin.net](https://www.arin.net/) to name a few. The IP addresses these registrars are responsible for are non-sequential in blocks. There are lists available by country where people have tried to collect these blocks in one place. [Nirsoft](http://www.nirsoft.net/countryip/) maintains some of these lists. They are not complete by any means and IP addresses change hands on a daily basis. If a block of IPs originally listed to a company in Australia is picked up by a corporation like Virgin Mobile or Microsoft, you may end up accidentally bouncing traffic in the UK or the US.

If you have access to the core server configs or have the ability to install packages, to keep traffic down on the server you can install or setup [iptables](http://www.netfilter.org/projects/iptables/) and have it block repeated attempts to areas you do not want traffic on. Also you can have it block any traffic that exceeds a speed threshold ('2 pages per second').

Let's say you have a hidden folder listed in [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/) that you're telling bots to disallow all. If you see traffic to that folder then you can assume it's someone who looked in [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/) and then decided to take a peek. This can be treated as a [honeypot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honeypot_%28computing%29). Additionally you can hide code that has no keyword value inside of your documents and make it non-visible to humans. When someone runs this code or follows a hidden link in the code you can also add them to the list of offenders if they're not obeying your robots.txt file.

You can also setup databases in MySQL and use a language like PHP for dropping connections (or redirecting offsite) that access a honeypot as well or addresses that try to brute force attack a login form or an FTP account. I implement databases on web forms to keep track of people who have already completed the form. If there are multiple spam attempts they're added to my blacklist.

It's much easier to block users with a reverse look-up and searching out their TLD for their country code or by blocking users whose browser asks for a page in a specific native language than it is to block ranges of IP addresses.

**Back to your example**

In your code, each of the [RewriteCond](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) lines should be true unless you're using [or]. Here is a more in-depth reference for [access restrictions with Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/access.html)

`REMOTE_HOST` is for domain names... so this line:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} ^1\.2\.3\.0/154
```

Should be using `REMOTE_ADDR` instead:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^1\.2\.3\.(1[0-4][0-9]|15[0-4]|[0-9][0-9]|[0-9])$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ australia-ip-restriction [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Is there a website that generates this IP addresses by country so I can put them inside my .htaccess file?

Comment: That pattern wouldn't match 1.2.3.149 or 1.2.3.77